# Is there anyway to avoid use `memcpy` when dealing with 2D Array at splitting dataset step in decision tree?

Tags: c, pointers, decision-tree

I'm trying to code [binary decision tree](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/decision-tree-introduction-example/). The below code is a working example for data splitting as a part of the whole algorithm although it has some [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMsdF.png) detected by Valgrind.

As you may already know, the tree is composed of nodes. In every node, it carries all the qualified observations(rows) by the splitting condition. Continue on, the splitting relies on those rows as well.

And the best split condition can be found from a greedy search through all the variables and values, which means this data splitting step could execute hundreds of times to find the optimal splitting(evaluate by Gini index in classification problem).  I thought it could be expensive when using `memcpy`. The worst part is I have to free the memory for the copied rows after each splitting attempt.

So, I was thinking if there is a way to avoid using `memcpy` to copy the entire dataset literally, instead, just reference the qualified rows of the original dataset in each splitting. In this way, no excessive `memcpy` and `free` are needed.

Question: To be specific for the below example, how to use one pointer to record the address of the qualified rows so that no `memcpy` is needed and allow (easy or handy) access to qualified rows when performing a greedy search for optimal splitting.

Let me know if the question is not clear to you. Thanks so much for your time.

Any help and suggestion are welcome.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void printArray(double array[], unsigned int size) {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        printf("%.3f  ", array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

double **alloc_2dArray(unsigned int row, unsigned int col)
{
    double **Array = (double **) malloc(row * sizeof(double *));

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        Array[i] = (double *) malloc(col * sizeof(double));
    }

    return Array;
}

void dealloc_2dArray(double **Array, unsigned int row, unsigned int col)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        free(Array[i]);
    }
    free(Array);
}

int main(){

    double **data = alloc_2dArray(4,4);
    double delta[4] = {1,0,1,0};

    double **dataL = alloc_2dArray(4,4);
    double **dataR = alloc_2dArray(4,4);

    int i,j;

    int k=0;
    //data initialization
    for(i=0; i<4; i++){
        for(j=0; j<4; j++){
            data[i][j] = k++;
        }
    }

    int l=0, r=0;

    for(i=0; i<4; i++){
        if((int)delta[i] ==0){
            memcpy(dataL[l++], data[i], 4*sizeof(double));
        }else{
            memcpy(dataR[r++], data[i], 4*sizeof(double));
        }
    }

    for(i = l; i<4; i++){
        free(dataL[i]);
    }

    printf("l and r are %d %d\n", l, r);

    dataL = realloc(dataL, l*sizeof(double*));

    for(i = r; i<4; i++){
        free(dataR[i]);
    }

    dataR = realloc(dataR, r*sizeof(double*));

    for(i=0; i<4; i++){
        if(dataL[i] != NULL){
            printArray(dataL[i],4);
        }
        if(dataR[i] != NULL){
            printArray(dataR[i],4);
        }
    }

    dealloc_2dArray(data, 4,4);
    dealloc_2dArray(dataL, l, 4);
    dealloc_2dArray(dataR, r, 4);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your final for-loop breaches `dataL`. Previous it was reallocated to be `2` slots wide, yet that loop enumerates [0..4) . The same problem happens with `dataR` for the same reason.

Comment: Aside: instead of  `Array[i] = (double *) malloc(col * sizeof(double));`, consider `Array[i] = malloc(sizeof Array[i][0] * col);`.  Easier to code right with less guess work, easier to review and maintain.  Likewise for `double **Array =...`.  I suggest this because, as is, code is unnecessarily harder to review.

Comment: yuw444, Curious, why the cast in `if((int)delta[i] ==0){`?

Comment: @WhozCraig I see. Thanks for pointing that all. Original, I thought dataL[3] != NULL would catch the unallocated memory. Apparently, it is my mistake.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica. Thanks for the suggestion. Besides, the condition is for the demo purpose of `data` splitting, not completely true in the Decision Tree algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* you're asking whether you can just retain the original data row pointers in the split matrices. The answer is yes, you can. Ownership comes into play, however.

For the example below (which has no `memcpy` operations) both the `dataL` and `dataR` pointer beds are direct-allocated with no actual rows of data assigned to them. The rows are "borrowed" from the original data matrix.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void printArray(double const array[], unsigned int size)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        printf("%-7.3f", array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

double **alloc_2dArray(unsigned int row, unsigned int col)
{
    double **Array = malloc(row * sizeof(double *));

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        Array[i] = (double *)malloc(col * sizeof(double));
    }

    return Array;
}

void dealloc_2dArray(double **Array, unsigned int row)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        free(Array[i]);
    }
    free(Array);
}

int main()
{

    double **data = alloc_2dArray(4,4);
    double delta[4] = {1, 0, 1, 0};

    double **dataL = calloc(4, sizeof *dataL);
    double **dataR = calloc(4, sizeof *dataR);

    unsigned int i, j;

    double k = 0;

    // data initialization
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            data[i][j] = k;
            k += 1;
        }
    }
    printf("data[]\n");
    for (i=0; i<4; ++i)
        printArray(data[i], 4);
    fputc('\n', stdout);

    unsigned int l = 0, r = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        if ((int)delta[i] == 0)
        {
            dataL[l++] = data[i];
        }
        else
        {
            dataR[r++] = data[i];
        }
    }

    printf("l=%u r=%u\n", l, r);
    dataL = realloc(dataL, l * sizeof(double *));
    dataR = realloc(dataR, r * sizeof(double *));

    printf("dataL[]\n");
    for (i=0; i<l; ++i)
        printArray(dataL[i], 4);
    fputc('\n', stdout);

    printf("dataR[]\n");
    for (i=0; i<r; ++i)
        printArray(dataR[i], 4);
    fputc('\n', stdout);

    free(dataL);
    free(dataR);
    dealloc_2dArray(data,4);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
data[]
0.000  1.000  2.000  3.000  
4.000  5.000  6.000  7.000  
8.000  9.000  10.000 11.000 
12.000 13.000 14.000 15.000 

l=2 r=2
dataL[]
4.000  5.000  6.000  7.000  
12.000 13.000 14.000 15.000 

dataR[]
0.000  1.000  2.000  3.000  
8.000  9.000  10.000 11.000
```

Regarding actual ownership of those row pointers. Only you know what is appropriate there. If the original `data` matrix is to continue to own them, you must take care to ensure that `data` and its rows are not destroyed while `dataL` and `dataR` are still in use. Likewise, if `dataR` and `dataL` are to take ownership, then you should not free those rows when freeing `data` (but still free the base pointer bed of `data`), and have `dataL` and `dataR` free'ing be responsible for freeing not only their base pointer beds, but the rows as well.

Anyway, there you go.

Comment: Hi, WhozCraig! I wrote a function that does what you suggested, but it gives me a segmentation error on Linux but works fine on the Mac M1 chip. Could you help me take a look?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72037721/11954034

Comment: What would you expect if I move `dealloc_2dArray(data)` before the printing?  The behavior quite surprises me. I thought `printArray()` would be undefined as the original `data` has been freed which `dataL` and `dataR` point to. 

But the printing works fine in fact. Then, I thought maybe the memory space hasn't gotten a chance to reset. So, I added `calloc(10000, sizeof(double)` in the hope to reset the memory `data` taken before.  Still, the printing works fine. Any insight what happened here?

Comment: Dereferencing deallocated dynamic memory invokes *undefined behavior*. It may seem like it works, but seeming isn't formal definition. It never "works" . It just seems like it did/does, and honestly that's the worst possible condition to be in, as it lulls the engineer into a false sense of accomplishment and assumption that seeing-is-believing, and they conclude that *observed* behavior is equivalent to *defined* behavior. They're only equivalent when the latter comes *first* (defined behavior). Only *then* can you trust what you observe.

Comment: Thanks for your insight, confirmation, and suggestion. I agree. FYI, the reason I am attempting this is trying to confirm if the memory space has been freed. In my project of the decision tree, this function is used in a recursive way where I have to free the `data` in the previous iteration.

Comment: You cannot confirm any memory region, dynamic or otherwise, is "freed" in standard C. The state should be conveyed by other means, for example, proper maintenance of the pointers that once-bound you to said memory. When no longer needed **and** properly freed, don't let the pointer dangle if it will live on for some future, non-immediate use: set it to null. There are obviously many ways to accomplish the same outcome, but ultimately that is one of the easiest to code and understand.

Comment: Thanks, I see. Speak of which, in the case of `data`, should I just set `data=null` __only__ after the dealloc? There is no need to set `data[i] = null`, right?

Comment: The code I proposed was *specifically* to loan the row pointers within `data` to `dataL` and `dataR`. The `data` sequence still owns those pointers as far as the demonstrated code is concerned. Thus the reason the `dataL` and `dataR` pointer beds are freed, but the pointers *within* are not; that is taken care of by `dealloc_2dArray(data,4);`.  The program exits immediately afterward, so setting `data = NULL;` seems pointless at that point.