# Allocate memory for top level of a double pointer

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

A few days ago, I asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71961456/is-there-anyway-to-avoid-use-memcpy-when-dealing-with-2d-array-at-splitting-da) in the community and received the answer quickly from our fellows. The solution is great on Valgrind as well.

And based on his/her suggestion, I wrote the following function for `split_dataset` as a part of the decision tree algorithm. Below is the code I wrote,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void printArray(double array[], unsigned int size)
{
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    printf("%.3f  ", array[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
}

typedef struct
{
    size_t length;
    double **designMatrix_Y;
} DecisionTreeData;

DecisionTreeData *split_dataset(int index,                    //var index
                                double value,                 //best cutoff
                                int row,                      //nrows of design matrix, number of variables
                                double **designMatrix_Y)      //design matrix (X) and response Y
{
    // Buffers to hold rows of data as we are distributing rows based on the split.
    double **leftDesignMatrix_Y        = calloc(row, sizeof *leftDesignMatrix_Y);
    double **rightDesignMatrix_Y       = calloc(row, sizeof *rightDesignMatrix_Y);

    size_t left_count = 0;
    size_t right_count = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < row; ++i)
    {

        if (designMatrix_Y[index][i] <= value)
        {
            // Copy the row into the left half
            leftDesignMatrix_Y[left_count]    = designMatrix_Y[i];
            left_count++;

        }
        else
        {
            // Copy the row into the right half
            rightDesignMatrix_Y[right_count]    = designMatrix_Y[i];
            right_count++;

        }

        //realloc the memory for exact space
        leftDesignMatrix_Y  = realloc(leftDesignMatrix_Y, left_count * sizeof(double *));
        rightDesignMatrix_Y = realloc(rightDesignMatrix_Y, right_count * sizeof(double *));

    }

    DecisionTreeData *data_split = malloc(sizeof(DecisionTreeData) * 2);

    data_split[0] = (DecisionTreeData){left_count, leftDesignMatrix_Y};
    data_split[1] = (DecisionTreeData){right_count, rightDesignMatrix_Y};

    return data_split;
}

double *alloc_dvector(unsigned int length)
{
  return malloc((length * (sizeof(double))));
}

void dealloc_dvector(double *array)
{
  free((char *) array);
}

double **alloc_2dArray(unsigned int row, unsigned int col)
{
  double **Array = (double **) malloc((size_t) ((row) * (sizeof(double *))));

  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    Array[i] = alloc_dvector(col);
  }

  return Array;
}

void dealloc_2dArray(double **Array, unsigned int row, unsigned int col)
{
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < row; i++)
  {
    dealloc_dvector(Array[i]);
  }
  free((char *) Array);
}

int main()
{

  double **designMatrix_Y = alloc_2dArray(4,4);

  for(int i = 0; i<4; i++)
  {
    for(int j= 0; j<4; j++)
    {
      designMatrix_Y[i][j] = i*j;
    }
  }


  DecisionTreeData *dataSplits = split_dataset(2,
                                               2, 
                                               4,
                                               designMatrix_Y);

  //rename for convenience
  size_t leftSize  = (dataSplits[0]).length;
  double **designMatrix_Y_L = (dataSplits[0]).designMatrix_Y;
  double **designMatrix_Y_R = (dataSplits[1]).designMatrix_Y;

  for(int i = 0; i<leftSize; ++i)
    printArray(designMatrix_Y_L[i],4);

  free(designMatrix_Y_L);
  free(designMatrix_Y_R);
  free(dataSplits);

  dealloc_2dArray(designMatrix_Y,4,4);

  return 0;
  

}
```

It works fine in my mac mini M1(doesn't support Valgrind, couldn't see the log) but crashed(segmentation fault) on Linux. Also, I have attached the error message from Valgrind with the code above.

```
==4777== LEAK SUMMARY:
==4777==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4777==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4777==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4777==    still reachable: 224 bytes in 8 blocks
==4777==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4777==
==4777== ERROR SUMMARY: 5 errors from 4 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==4777==
==4777== 1 errors in context 1 of 4:
==4777== Invalid read of size 8
==4777==    at 0x4006C7: printArray (test.c:7)
==4777==    by 0x400A5E: main (test.c:117)
==4777==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==4777==
==4777==
==4777== 1 errors in context 2 of 4:
==4777== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==4777==    at 0x4006C7: printArray (test.c:7)
==4777==    by 0x400A5E: main (test.c:117)
==4777==
==4777==
==4777== 1 errors in context 3 of 4:
==4777== Invalid write of size 8
==4777==    at 0x4007B4: split_dataset (test.c:36)
==4777==    by 0x400A06: main (test.c:106)
==4777==  Address 0x52052e8 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==4777==    at 0x4C2C291: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:834)
==4777==    by 0x400809: split_dataset (test.c:49)
==4777==    by 0x400A06: main (test.c:106)
==4777==
==4777==
==4777== 2 errors in context 4 of 4:
==4777== Invalid write of size 8
==4777==    at 0x4007E7: split_dataset (test.c:43)
==4777==    by 0x400A06: main (test.c:106)
==4777==  Address 0x5205380 is 0 bytes after a block of size 0 alloc'd
==4777==    at 0x4C29EBD: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:306)
==4777==    by 0x4C2C210: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:834)
==4777==    by 0x400828: split_dataset (test.c:50)
==4777==    by 0x400A06: main (test.c:106)
==4777==
==4777== ERROR SUMMARY: 5 errors from 4 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
(END)
```

With the error code, I realized the error may arise from `printArray()`. So, I ran it one more time without the for loop of `printArray()`. The log from Valgrind changed as follows.

```
==4021== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4021==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4021==   total heap usage: 15 allocs, 15 frees, 336 bytes allocated
==4021==
==4021== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==4021==
==4021== ERROR SUMMARY: 3 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==4021==
==4021== 1 errors in context 1 of 2:
==4021== Invalid write of size 8
==4021==    at 0x4007B4: split_dataset (test.c:36)
==4021==    by 0x400A06: main (test.c:106)
==4021==  Address 0x52052e8 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==4021==    at 0x4C2C291: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:834)
==4021==    by 0x400809: split_dataset (test.c:49)
==4021==    by 0x400A06: main (test.c:106)
==4021==
==4021==
==4021== 2 errors in context 2 of 2:
==4021== Invalid write of size 8
==4021==    at 0x4007E7: split_dataset (test.c:43)
==4021==    by 0x400A06: main (test.c:106)
==4021==  Address 0x5205380 is 0 bytes after a block of size 0 alloc'd
==4021==    at 0x4C29EBD: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:306)
==4021==    by 0x4C2C210: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:834)
==4021==    by 0x400828: split_dataset (test.c:50)
==4021==    by 0x400A06: main (test.c:106)
==4021==
==4021== ERROR SUMMARY: 3 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
(END)
```

So, can anyone help with this issue? Any suggestion? Thanks for your time in advance for my tedious description. Let me know if anything unclear.

gcc version 9.3.0

Comment: Aside: simplify `return (double *) malloc((size_t) ((length) * (sizeof(double))));` --> `return malloc(length *  sizeof(double));`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, thanks for the tip. Appreciate you taking the time to look over the code and question.

Comment: Note `col` is not used in `split_dataset()`.  Is that reasonable as part of the function goal?

Comment: Oh, you are right. it is not in use right now.

Comment: Same with `rightSize` in `size_t rightSize = (dataSplits[1]).length;`: unused.

Comment: Yes. I will try to make a minimal example and update it later. You are right, the extra variables may confuse others.

Comment: Sure about 4 in `printArray(designMatrix_Y_L[i], 4);`?

Comment: Don't include images of text information — they're unreadable, even on a big screen, let alone on a cell phone.  See also [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/15168)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for the suggestion. I will make them in text format.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, `designMatrix_Y_L[i]` should point to one of the rows in `designMatrix_Y`if it is working correctly. In this case, 4 is the number of columns in `designMatrix_Y`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Just realise you bring up your first Aside for me second time.(first time in my last question post) I'm really sorry about that. Thanks so much for your consistent help. Just curious, could you reproduce the same error message from your end?

Comment: Works for me on Linux x64 with both -O0 and -O3.

Comment: @Joshua Do you mean both cases passed memory check on your end?

Comment: @yuw444: I thought you said it crashed. I don't have a memory checker.

Comment: @Joshua Sorry,  I should make it more clear. It was giving `segmentation fault` on my end. The following contents are logs from Valgrind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two reallocs don't belong where they are *inside* that for-loop. The should be *after* the for-loop when the final sizes of the resulting left/ride splits are firm. By resizing them on each iteration you're fixing them to their current size, which means, the next iteration will guarantee to be out-of-range by one slot (no matter which side is the target). An address sanitizer report will confirm this.

Both sides were intentionally over allocated to hold `row` potential pointers. Those only need adjustment trimming once the dust settles after the split iterations are done.

This (marked HERE) below:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < row; ++i)
{

    if (designMatrix_Y[index][i] <= value)
    {
        // Copy the row into the left half
        leftDesignMatrix_Y[left_count]    = designMatrix_Y[i];
        left_count++;

    }
    else
    {
        // Copy the row into the right half
        rightDesignMatrix_Y[right_count]    = designMatrix_Y[i];
        right_count++;

    }

    // HERE HERE HERE HERE HERE
    //realloc the memory for exact space
    leftDesignMatrix_Y  = realloc(leftDesignMatrix_Y, left_count * sizeof(double *));
    rightDesignMatrix_Y = realloc(rightDesignMatrix_Y, right_count * sizeof(double *));

}
```

should be like this:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < row; ++i)
{

    if (designMatrix_Y[index][i] <= value)
    {
        // Copy the row into the left half
        leftDesignMatrix_Y[left_count]    = designMatrix_Y[i];
        left_count++;

    }
    else
    {
        // Copy the row into the right half
        rightDesignMatrix_Y[right_count]    = designMatrix_Y[i];
        right_count++;

    }
}

//realloc the memory for exact space
leftDesignMatrix_Y  = realloc(leftDesignMatrix_Y, left_count * sizeof(double *));
rightDesignMatrix_Y = realloc(rightDesignMatrix_Y, right_count * sizeof(double *));
```

Comment: Thanks so much for saving me one more time. You have no idea how much appreciate you. I know inviting you for a dinner may be difficult, but I can buy you a cup of tea/coffee if possible.